# Android: Where must I put licenses of libraries being used?

Tags: android

I use a bunch of external libraries in my program and part of their license agreement is that I should put their license and what not in my application somehow. Where is this type of information usually stored in an Android application? And what is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a button or a link somewhere, perhaps in your Settings activity if you have one, which displays a page with the relevant license information.

Comment: Ah the settings page! Thanks!